# Count the number of items in a dictionary inside a list as per the dictionary value

Tags: python

I have a dictionary inside a list structured like:

```
my_list = [
 {
     "id" : 1,
     "name" : "foo",
     "address" : "here"
 },
 {
     "id" : 2,
     "name" : "foo2",
     "address" : "there"
  },
 {
     "id" : 3,
     "name" : "foo3",
     "address" : "there"
  },
]
```

How do I get the total count of particular address? Say like i want to know how many people are from address "there". How do I do that??

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Iterate over the list and count how many have the address 'there'

Comment: So far I tried iterating through the loop using Counter, but apparently this gave me the count of each word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use len function along with list_comprehension.

```
>>> my_list = [
 {
     id : 1,
     'name' : 'foo',
     'address' : 'here'
 },
 {
     id : 2,
     'name' : 'foo2',
     'address' : 'there'
  },
 {
     id : 3,
     'name' : 'foo3',
     'address' : 'there'
  },
]
>>> len([x for x in my_list if x['address'] == 'there'])
2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
count = 0
for dictionary in my_list:
    if dictionary["address"] == "there":
        count+=1
print count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum` function like following,*Note* that you need to loop over your dictionaries and check if the value of your target key is `there`! :

```
sum(1 for d in my_list if d['address']=='there')
```

Demo :

```
>>> my_list = [
...  {
...      'id' : 1,
...      'name' : 'foo',
...      'address' : 'here'
...  },
...  {
...      'id' : 2,
...      'name' : 'foo2',
...      'address' : 'there'
...   },
...  {
...      'id' : 3,
...      'name' : 'foo3',
...      'address' : 'there'
...   },
... ]
>>> sum(1 for d in my_list if d['address']=='there')
2
```

Comment: @Dan you're welcome! so you can tell this to community also by vote and accepting the answer! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**collections.Counter**](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and list comprehensions

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = Counter([addr["address"] for addr in my_list])
>>> d["there"]
2
```

Answer (score 1):

In case `address` field might be missing for some entries you can use `.get()` method.

```
sum(x.get('address') == "there" for x in my_list)
```

Comment: This one is new for me!! thanks will try this later.